# Scrolling animation on Flutter has bad performance: strange raster thread behavior

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app using Flutter, where I simply want a rectangle to move on screen when I scroll with my fingers (on Android/iOS) or when I scroll with a mouse wheel or trackpad (on web).

This is what my code looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

/////////////////

void main()
{
  runApp(MyCustomScroller());
}

/////////////////

class MyCustomScroller extends StatefulWidget
{    
  @override
  _MyCustomScrollerState createState() => _MyCustomScrollerState();
}

class _MyCustomScrollerState extends State<MyCustomScroller> with TickerProviderStateMixin 
{
  AnimationController animController;
  double scrollPos = 500;

  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();

    animController = AnimationController.unbounded(
      vsync: this,
      value: 0,
    );

    animController.addListener(()
    {
      setState(()
      {
        scrollPos = animController.value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose()
  {
    animController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }


  void _onScrollUpdate(final double velPpf)
  {
    final double velPps = velPpf*60;

    Simulation sim = ClampingScrollSimulation(
      position: scrollPos,
      velocity: velPps,
      friction: 0.01,
    );
    animController.animateWith(sim);

    scrollPos += velPpf;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scrolling Test',
      home: Listener(
        onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent moveEvent) // mobile, web click or web finger (on mobile)
        {
          _onScrollUpdate(moveEvent.delta.dy);
        },
        onPointerSignal: (PointerSignalEvent signalEvent) // web scrolling wheel/trackpad
        {
          if (signalEvent is PointerScrollEvent)
            _onScrollUpdate(-signalEvent.scrollDelta.dy);
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: MyPainter(
              pos: scrollPos,
            ),
            child: Container(),
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

/////////////////

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter
{
  final double pos;

  MyPainter({
    @required this.pos
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size)
  {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 12
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
        
    final double x = size.width/2;
    final double y = (pos % size.height*1.5) - size.height*0.25;
    final Offset offset0 = Offset(x, y);
    final Offset offset1 = Offset(x, y+size.height*0.25);

    canvas.drawLine(offset0, offset1, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, I can see a rectangle that moves up and down as I scroll. When I stop scrolling, the `AnimationController` continues moving the rectangle. I know similar results can be achieved using a `GestureDetector` instead of a `Listener`, but a `GestureDetector` does not work on mouse scrolling on web.

The problem comes when I run my app in profiling mode: I turn on the Performance Overlay to see if the UI and Raster threads are executing fine and that I don't have any jank.

Most of the time the performance of the raster thread looks fine, as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

However sometimes, for some reason, the time taken to render a frame on the Raster thread goes up to around 16-17 ms, as you can see in the following image, and then stays around those values for the upcoming frames, until the animation finishes:

[image]

Anybody has any idea why this happens?

Comment: what is the reason for `AnimationController.animateWith` inside `_onScrollUpdate` ?

Comment: The purpose is that it continues animating after I stop scrolling. When using a `GestureDetector` this could be done in the `onVerticalDragEnd` method callback, but as I said I am using a `Listener` because I want to also capture `PointerScrollEvent`s when scrolling on web, and this one does not have an `onEnd` callback.

Comment: but you have `onPointerUp` - this is the place where you should `animateWith`

Comment: also you can use both: `child: Listener(
onPointerSignal: print,
child: GestureDetector(
onVerticalDragUpdate: print,
child: Container(color: Colors.orange),
),
),`

Comment: thank you for your code, it works great but my post was more oriented to knowing why the Raster thread behaves like that. I would like to understand why it takes much longer sometimes to render a frame, when the code is the same on every execution of `_onScrollUpdate`.